# How to hide the object of the OLE controler?

Tags: vb6, media-player, ole, visible

I'm working with the `OLE object` using VB6. I use it to play a sound when a certain condition is true. The `OLE` class is `MPlayer`. The problem is that I don't want the player to be visible. I know that I can set the `Visible` property of the `OLE control` to false, but thats just hides the conrtrol itself, but not the `MPlayer` itself. I've tried the following:

```
    If Something Then
        ' Starts the music.
        OLEPlayer.Action = 7
        ' Here, which line I should use to hide the MPlayer itself?
        ' OLEPlayer.Visible = False - hides just the controler, and not its class.
        ' There is no Visible property to the Class.
    Else
        ' Stops the music.
        oleAlarmSound.Action = 9
    End If
```

I've looked everywhere, but since there is a minor support for VB6 in general, and VB6 ole in particular, i've found nothing.

Comment: If you just want to play a sound the PlaySound API can do that invisibly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Screen.Width
Screen.Height
object.Top
object.Left
```

to move the object out of the screen area